# Relational pouch methods aren't available in Angular Service

Tags: angular, pouchdb, relational-pouch

I'm trying to get relational-pouch working, I'm able to set the schema but when I call the save function I get the error `TypeError: this.rel.save is not a function`

This is the setup:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser'
import find from 'pouchdb-find'
import rel from 'relational-pouch'

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PouchDBService {

    public base_db: PouchDB.Database
    public rel

    constructor() {
        PouchDB.plugin(find)
        PouchDB.plugin(rel)
        this.base_db = new PouchDB('Eeeek')
        this.rel = this.base_db.setSchema(schema)
        this.rel.save('project', {
            name: 'George R. R. Martin', id: 1, books: [6, 7]
        })
    }
}
```

When I try to call `this.rel.find(id)` it seems to be ignoring the *relational-pouch* definition and using the *pouch-find* definition. So `this.rel.find(id)` results in `Error: you must provide search parameters to find()`

but

```
            this.db.rel.find({
                selector: {
                    type: this.type
                }
            })
```

works.

The dependencies seem fine, I'm stumped, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

ps. using angular 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `rel` field as advertised.  From the type declaration `rel` is defined as

```typescript
interface RelDatabase<Content extends {} = {}> extends Database<Content> {
   rel: RelDB;
}
```

<s>so I don't understand how this code is compiling</s>
It's compiling because `rel` is implied as `any`

```typescript
   public base_db: PouchDB.Database
   public rel
    . . . 
   this.rel = this.base_db.setSchema(schema)
   this.rel.save('project', {
      name: 'George R. R. Martin', id: 1, books: [6, 7]
   })
```

This is a benefit of Typescript, and would've saved you a ton of wonder:

```typescript
public rel: PouchDB.RelDatabase;
```

This is what you're looking for (kinda)

```typescript
   this.rel = this.base_db.setSchema(schema)
   this.rel.rel.save('project', {
      name: 'George R. R. Martin', id: 1, books: [6, 7]
   })
```

But that's awful to read - I recommend

```typescript
export class PouchDBService {
   // why have a service if these are public...
   private db: PouchDB.Database;
   private rdb: PouchDB.RelDatabase;
```

Anyway the major takeaway here is to use explicit types. This is demonstrably correct:

```typescript
db: PouchDB.Database;
rdb: PouchDB.RelDatabase;

async demoRelDb(dbName: string): Promise<any> {
    PouchDB.plugin(find).plugin(rel);
    this.db = new PouchDB(dbName);  
    this.rdb = this.db.setSchema([
        { singular: "author", plural: "authors", relations: { books: { hasMany: "book" } } },
        { singular: "book", plural: "books", relations: { author: { belongsTo: "author" } } },
    ]);
    
    await this.rdb.rel.save("author", {
        name: "George R. R. Martin",
        id: 1,
        books: [6, 7],
    });         
    let result await this.rdb.rel.find("author", 1);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, undefined, 3));
}
```

OK great now you should be on your way.  However I am warning people away from using this plugin as it appears practically abandoned, and issue [#125](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch/issues/125) is a showstopper.

Until some maintenance happens - there are 16 pull requests spanning 2 years - I would not use it.  If anything search for a viable fork.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. Makes perfect sense, but I think your final comment *don't use it* is probably the most helpful. I'm starting to dig the views and complex keys, bit of a different mindset, but very powerful and useful it seems so far. If I'm going to use it, I may as well use it properly I guess. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You are most welcome and I am glad to have helped!